# Filtering table by country

Tags: jquery, filter, tablefilter

HI i have a table and i need to filter by last column with dropdown <select>.
My filtering if country does not exist removing all rows <tr>
But if country exist adding all rows but i need one row with this country not all.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#select_country').on('change', function () {
            var selected = $(this).val();
            var tr = $('tr');
            var td = $('td:last-child').text().trim();
            if (td.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
                $(tr).removeClass('cashback_filter_none');
            } else {
                $(tr).addClass('cashback_filter_none');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your issue is `$(tr).addClass` - where `tr = $("tr")` - so you have `$("tr").addClass` - which will clearly add the class to all tr.   Equally `$('td:last-child').text()` is only one value - the text of all cells in the last column combined.  Please *do* add some *basic* debuggng - check what `$('td:last-child').text().trim()` *actually* is - check `$('td:last-child').length` and `$(tr).length` so you can see what it is that you're selecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're are comparing the *value* of the `#select_country` to the *text* of the last `td`. That doesn't seem right. You should verify that is the case by `console.log` the values for debugging.

A good idea is to store the value of each country cell as an attribute upfront.

Example:

```js
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("change", function(ev) {
  var filter = this.value
  document.querySelectorAll("table td").forEach(function(td) {
    if (td.getAttribute("data-value") == filter || filter == "") {
      td.classList.remove("hide")
    } else {
      td.classList.add("hide")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
  <option value="1">Spain</option>
  <option value="2">Italy</option>
  <option value="3">Israel</option>
  <option value="4">Japan</option>
</select>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-value="3">Israel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-value="4">Japan</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note: the `.value` of a `<option>` is the same as its `.innerText` if the option does not have a `value=` value. Equally an `option` `value=` can be text.  So comparing the *value* of `select` against the *text* of a `td` is perfectly valid and highly likely.   It's more likely that the straight `===` is not considering whitespace within the `td` (but they do have `.trim()`)  **Edit** looked at OPs code - their issue is that they're selected all text from the last column tds in one go and compared the whole lot - as well as selecting all trs to add/remove class instead of the ones that match.

Comment: Solution to loop the `td`s is the correct solution (ofc) just not explained in the text.

Comment: value from in select from db

Comment: It's does not working because the values in select from bd does not equals to values in table from bd

Comment: but both should be taken from same source, shouldn't they? how is the html (of table and select) generated?